# Is it possible in Scala to create a partial curried function using an anonymous function

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, currying

I'm new to scala, and just playing around with some code. I created a curried function from an example I found online line this:

```
    def adder(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

    var addto = (adder _ ).curried
```

and it works. But, when I try replacing adder with an anonymous function like..

```
    var addto = ({(a :Int, b: Int) => a + b} _ ).curried
```

I get an error saying:

```
    error: _ must follow method; cannot follow (Int, Int) => Int
```

any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need placeholder (`_`)

```
scala> var addto = ({(a :Int, b: Int) => a + b}  ).curried
addto: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala> addto(1)
res0: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res0(2)
res1: Int = 3
```

This is because you already have a function object with you here on which you can call [curried](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2).

Where as in your previous case

```
var addto = (adder _ ).curried
```

You first had to convert the method to a function object (by using placeholder) before doing `curried` on it.

Comment: `def` defines a method, while `val` and `var` result in a function.

Comment: `adder` is a method. When we say function, i.e. when you do `adder _` you get a `Function2[Int, Int, Int]` object.

Comment: Interesting. I always though of methods as being attached to an object. When the code gets compiled is it attached to an object? What is the object?

Comment: Yes method is attached to object. They are no different entities. But when we refer function in scala, we refer to an independent object which takes input and gives output. It is just like any other variable. Method has an association to the object, i.e. like a property of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var addto = ((a :Int, b: Int) => a + b ).curried
```